# Blank Pages when creating a PDF file using Itext PDF

Tags: java, itext

Whenever I am running the below code in my local machine, this is working as expected, but when I try to execute the same in the server, blank pages are getting created at the beginning, no header is also getting added. But if the record is less and of one page pdf is getting created as desired.

```
public class StatementPrintingTemp implements Serializable
    {  
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Font fontColour_bold =  FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font fontColour_NormalUnderline =  FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.NORMAL|Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font fontColour_Normal =  FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font bfBold12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)); 
        Font bf12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9); 
        Font bf12bold = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9,Font.BOLD); 
        Document doc = null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
                Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(130, 150, 60));
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
                Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
                Font.BOLD);
        private static Font smallBold = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 7, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        private static Font smallNormal = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 7, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("consoleLogger");
        static {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Config" + File.separator
                    + "log4j_WebServiceWrapper.properties");
    
            // **********Read the attributes from NG_SERVICE.xml****************
            String log4jConfigFile = "";
            logger = Logger.getLogger("common_logger");
            log4jConfigFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "log4j.properties";
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfigFile);
    
        }
        
        public String executetemp(String workitemName,String salno, String templatename, String sessionid, String processName) {
            DMSOperation objDmsOper = null;
            ReadServerProperty prop = null;
            String outputXML = "";
            WFSession wfSession = null;
            Properties property = null;
            String propFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Config" + File.separator
                    + "serverdetail.properties";
            logger.info("propFilePath = " + propFilePath);
            System.out.print(propFilePath);
            try {
    
                wfSession = new WFSession();
                objDmsOper = new DMSOperation();
                property = new Properties();
                property.load(new FileInputStream(propFilePath));
                String serverPath = property.getProperty("TEMPLATEUTILPATH");
                logger.info("Server Path " + serverPath);
                PropertyConfigurator.configure(serverPath + "/TemplateGeneration/log4j.properties");
                logger.info("Logging configured");
                prop = new ReadServerProperty(propFilePath);
                // Create Connection
                if (objDmsOper.createNGEJBConnection(prop)) {
                    if (objDmsOper.connecttoDMS(sessionid)) {
                        outputXML = generateTemplate(wfSession, objDmsOper, prop, workitemName,salno,templatename , serverPath, processName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("Error in main:" + CommonFunctions.getStackTrace(e));
            } finally {
                objDmsOper = null;
                prop = null;
                property = null;
                wfSession = null;
            }
            return outputXML;
        } 
        public String generateTemplate(WFSession wfSession, DMSOperation objDmsOper, ReadServerProperty prop,
                String workitemName,String salno, String templateName, String serverPath,String ProcessName)
        {
            String sDOCAddXML ="";
            PdfWriter docWriter = null;
            String path = "";
            String sCurrentDate="";
            String WI_NUMBER = "";
            String ACCOUNT_STATUS ="";
            String ACCT_OPEN_DATE="";
            XMLParser parserObj = new XMLParser();
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String TRAN_DATE="",VALUE_DATE="",CHQ_NUM="",TRAN_DESC="",ACCT_CURR_CODE="",DEBIT_AMT="",CREDIT_AMT="",BAL_AMT="",FROM_DATE="",OPENING_BAL="",CLOSING_BAL="",ACCT_NAME="",ACC="";
            String newdt= "";
            String todt= "";
            try 
            {
                logger.info("salno : "+ salno);
                logger.info("workitemName : "+ workitemName +"\ntemplateName : "+templateName);
                
                String queryString = "Select WI_NUMBER,COUNTRY,CIF_ID,WI_NO,INITIATED_BY,convert (VARCHAR,convert(DATE,WI_INIT_DT),103) AS WI_INIT_DT,APP_NAME,ACC_NO,G_HOME_BRANCH_NAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS, ACCT_OPEN_DATE,format(getdate(),'dd-MM-yyyy') AS ACCT_STATUS_DATE,ACCT_CLOSING_DATE,format(FROM_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS FROM_DATE,format(TO_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS TO_DATE,PO_BOX,POSTAL_CODE,CITY, AREA,format(getdate(),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS CURRENTDATE,FOLDERINDEX FROM BD_SP_EXTTABLE WHERE WI_NO ='"+workitemName+"'";
                String outputXML = objDmsOper.dbValues(queryString, prop);
                        
                parserObj.setInputXML((outputXML));
    
                logger.info("queryString 1 is--" + queryString);
                logger.info("outputXML is--" + outputXML);
                logger.info("After query STring : " );
    
                String Name  =parserObj.getValueOf("APP_NAME");
                ACCOUNT_STATUS  =parserObj.getValueOf("ACCOUNT_STATUS");
                logger.info("ACCOUNT_STATUS : " +ACCOUNT_STATUS);
                ACCT_OPEN_DATE =parserObj.getValueOf("ACCT_OPEN_DATE");
                logger.info("ACCT_OPEN_DATE is--" + ACCT_OPEN_DATE);
                WI_NUMBER  =parserObj.getValueOf("WI_NUMBER");
                logger.info("WI_NUMBER: " +WI_NUMBER);
                String POBOX =parserObj.getValueOf("PO_BOX");
                String PC =parserObj.getValueOf("POSTAL_CODE");
                String City = parserObj.getValueOf("CITY")+","+parserObj.getValueOf("AREA");
                String Country ="SULTANATE OF OMAN";
                //parserObj.getValueOf("COUNTRY");
                String sAccountNo =salno;
                String initiatedby =parserObj.getValueOf("INITIATED_BY");
                String wi_no =workitemName;
                //String Area=parserObj.getValueOf("AREA");
                newdt= parserObj.getValueOf("FROM_DATE");
                sCurrentDate= parserObj.getValueOf("CURRENTDATE");
                todt= parserObj.getValueOf("TO_DATE");
                logger.info("newdt : "+ newdt +"\ntodt : "+todt);
    
                String queryChq = "select TRAN_DATE,VALUE_DATE,CHQ_NUM,TRAN_DESC,ACCT_CURR_CODE,DEBIT_AMT,CREDIT_AMT,BAL_AMT,FROM_DATE,OPENING_BAL,CLOSING_BAL,ACCT_NAME,ACC AS ACC_NO,getdate()'ACC_STATUS_DATE' FROM openquery(bpmfin,'select * from table ( custom.get_acc_stm_mfk(''"+salno+"'', to_date(''"+newdt+"'',''DD-MM-YYYY''), to_date(''"+todt+"'',''DD-MM-YYYY'')))')";
                
                logger.info("queryChq : " + queryChq);
                
                String sQueryChq =  objDmsOper.dbValues(queryChq, prop);
                logger.info("sQueryChq : " + sQueryChq);
                parser = new XMLParser();
                parser.setInputXML(sQueryChq);
    
                logger.info("sQueryChq : "+ newdt +"\ntodt : "+todt);
                String ACC_STATUS_DATE=parser.getValueOf("ACC_STATUS_DATE");
                logger.info("ACC_STATUS_DATE : " + ACC_STATUS_DATE);
                int Record =0;
                if(parser.getValueOf("MainCode").equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                {
                    Record  = Integer.parseInt(parser.getValueOf("TotalRetrieved"));
                }
                if(Record>0)
                {
                    Name = parser.getValueOf("ACCT_NAME");
                }
                int TotalPages =1;
                /*if(Record<=44)
                {
                    TotalPages = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    double remain = Record - 44;
    
                    TotalPages = (int) Math.ceil(remain/52) + 1;
                }*/
    
                logger.info("TOtal Pages : " + TotalPages);
                Document doc = new Document();
                docWriter = null;
    
    
                String destinationpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\TemplateGeneration\\generatedTemplates\\" + workitemName;
                File dirpath = new File(destinationpath);
    
                logger.info("destinationpath before-->>"+destinationpath);
                if(dirpath == null || !dirpath.isDirectory())
                {
                    dirpath.mkdir();
                }
    
                //file path
                path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\TemplateGeneration\\generatedTemplates\\" + workitemName + "\\" + templateName + ".pdf";
    
                logger.info("PATH  : " + path);
                docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc , new FileOutputStream(path));
                if (parserObj.getValueOf("MainCode").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) 
                {
                    try {   
    
                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(path));
                        doc.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
                        doc.setMargins(25, 25, 160, 40);
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
                        writer.setBoxSize("art", rect);
                        HeaderFooterPageEvent event = new HeaderFooterPageEvent(Name,POBOX,PC,City,Country ,initiatedby,wi_no,sAccountNo,TotalPages,sCurrentDate);
                        writer.setPageEvent(event);
                        
                        
                        doc.open();
    
    
                        Paragraph heading = new Paragraph();
                        float[] columnWidthsTop = {3f, 3f, 3f,3f};
                        //create PDF table with the given widths
                        PdfPTable tableTop = new PdfPTable(columnWidthsTop);
                        // set table width a percentage of the page width
                        tableTop.setWidthPercentage(100f);
    
                        insertCell(tableTop, "A/c.Status", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, ACCOUNT_STATUS, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
    
                        insertCell(tableTop, "A/c.Status Date", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, ACC_STATUS_DATE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, "A/c. Open Date", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, ACCT_OPEN_DATE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
    
                        insertCell(tableTop, "A/c. Close Date", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, "NA", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, "Opening Balance ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, parser.getFirstValueOf("OPENING_BAL"), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
    
                        insertCell(tableTop, "Available Amount", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, parser.getFirstValueOf("CLOSING_BAL"), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, "Closing Balance ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, parser.getFirstValueOf("CLOSING_BAL"), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
    
                        insertCell(tableTop, "Effective Available Amount", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12bold,false,false);
                        insertCell(tableTop, parser.getFirstValueOf("BAL_AMT"), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, bf12,false,false);
    
    
                        doc.add(tableTop);
    
                        heading = new Paragraph();
                        addEmptyLine(heading, 2);
                        doc.add(heading);
    
                        float[] columnWidths = {6f,6f,11f,33f,3f,8f,8f,7f};
                        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
                        table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
    
    
                        insertCell(table, "Tran.Date", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "Value Date", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "Instr.No", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "Particulars", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "CCY", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "Debit Amount", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "Credit Amount", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        insertCell(table, "Balance", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, smallBold,true,true);
                        table.setHeaderRows(1);
    
                        if(Record>0)
                        {
                            TRAN_DATE="";VALUE_DATE="";CHQ_NUM="";TRAN_DESC="";ACCT_CURR_CODE="";DEBIT_AMT="";CREDIT_AMT="";BAL_AMT="";FROM_DATE="";OPENING_BAL="";CLOSING_BAL="";ACCT_NAME="";ACC="";
                            if(Record==1)
                            {
                                TRAN_DATE=parser.getValueOf("TRAN_DATE");
                                VALUE_DATE=parser.getValueOf("VALUE_DATE");
                                CHQ_NUM=parser.getValueOf("CHQ_NUM");
                                TRAN_DESC=parser.getValueOf("TRAN_DESC");
                                ACCT_CURR_CODE=parser.getValueOf("ACCT_CURR_CODE");
                                DEBIT_AMT=parser.getValueOf("DEBIT_AMT");
                                CREDIT_AMT=parser.getValueOf("CREDIT_AMT");
                                BAL_AMT=parser.getValueOf("BAL_AMT");
                                FROM_DATE=parser.getValueOf("FROM_DATE");
                                OPENING_BAL=parser.getValueOf("OPENING_BAL");
                                CLOSING_BAL=parser.getValueOf("CLOSING_BAL");
                                ACCT_NAME=parser.getValueOf("ACCT_NAME");
                                ACC=parser.getValueOf("ACC");
    
                                insertCell(table, TRAN_DATE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, VALUE_DATE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, CHQ_NUM, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, TRAN_DESC, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, ACCT_CURR_CODE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, DEBIT_AMT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, CREDIT_AMT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                insertCell(table, BAL_AMT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String sXML ="";
                                for (int x=0; x<Record; x++)
                                {   
                                    sXML = parser.getNextValueOf("Record");
                                    XMLParser subParser = new XMLParser();
                                    subParser.setInputXML(sXML);
                                    TRAN_DATE="";VALUE_DATE="";CHQ_NUM="";TRAN_DESC="";ACCT_CURR_CODE="";DEBIT_AMT="";CREDIT_AMT="";BAL_AMT="";FROM_DATE="";OPENING_BAL="";CLOSING_BAL="";ACCT_NAME="";ACC="";
    
                                    TRAN_DATE=subParser.getValueOf("TRAN_DATE");
                                    VALUE_DATE=subParser.getValueOf("VALUE_DATE");
                                    CHQ_NUM=subParser.getValueOf("CHQ_NUM");
                                    TRAN_DESC=subParser.getValueOf("TRAN_DESC");
                                    ACCT_CURR_CODE=subParser.getValueOf("ACCT_CURR_CODE");
                                    DEBIT_AMT=subParser.getValueOf("DEBIT_AMT");
                                    CREDIT_AMT=subParser.getValueOf("CREDIT_AMT");
                                    BAL_AMT=subParser.getValueOf("BAL_AMT");
                                    FROM_DATE=subParser.getValueOf("FROM_DATE");
                                    OPENING_BAL=subParser.getValueOf("OPENING_BAL");
                                    CLOSING_BAL=subParser.getValueOf("CLOSING_BAL");
                                    ACCT_NAME=subParser.getValueOf("ACCT_NAME");
                                    ACC=subParser.getValueOf("ACC");
    
                                    insertCell(table, TRAN_DATE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, VALUE_DATE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, CHQ_NUM, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, TRAN_DESC, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, ACCT_CURR_CODE, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, DEBIT_AMT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, CREDIT_AMT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                    insertCell(table, BAL_AMT, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, smallNormal,false,true);
                                }
                            }
                            doc.add(table);
                        }
    
                        
    
                        doc.close();
    
                        System.out.println("Done");
                        logger.info("Value Inserted SucessFully");
                    }
                    catch (DocumentException dex)
                    {
                        dex.printStackTrace();
                        doc.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        doc.close();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (doc != null){
                            //close the document
                            doc.close();
                        }
                        if (docWriter != null){
                            //close the writer
                            docWriter.close();
                        }
                    }
                    
                    sDOCAddXML = objDmsOper.AddDocument(serverPath + "/TemplateGeneration/generatedTemplates/" + workitemName + "/"
                                    + templateName + ".pdf",
                            "N", workitemName, "pdf", prop, templateName);
    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                sDOCAddXML = "<Record><ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode><ErrorDesc>Error in generating the template. Contact to Bank BPM Team 1.</ErrorDesc>.</Record>";
                logger.info("Exception in doPost : " + e.toString());
                logger.info(" Inside catch---for Template Generation");
            }
            return sDOCAddXML;
        }
    
    
        private void insertCell(PdfPTable table, String text, int align, int colspan, Font font, boolean Header,boolean border){
    
            //create a new cell with the specified Text and Font
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text.trim(), font));
            //set the cell alignment
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
            //set the cell column span in case you want to merge two or more cells
            cell.setColspan(colspan);
            if(Header)
            {
                cell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(112,155,21));
            }
            if(!border)
            {
                cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            }
            //logger.info("base color : "+ BaseColor.GREEN);
            //in case there is no text and you wan to create an empty row
            if(text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                cell.setMinimumHeight(10f);
            }
            //add the call to the table
            table.addCell(cell);
    
        }
        private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
            }
        }
    }




**
public class HeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    Font bfBold12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)); 
    Font bf12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8); 
    Font bfnormal12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9); 
    private String name ="";
    private String City ="";
    private String Country ="";
    private String POBOX ="";
    private String PC ="";
    private String initiatedby ="";
    private String wi_name ="";
    private String sAccountNo="";
    private int TotalPages =1;
    private String sCurrentDate ="";
    public HeaderFooterPageEvent(String name,String POBOX, String PC,String City,String Country, String initiatedby, String wi_name,String sAccountNo,int TotalPages,String sCurrentDate) 
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.City = City;
        this.initiatedby = initiatedby;
        this.wi_name=wi_name;
        this.POBOX=POBOX;
        this.PC = PC;
        this.Country = Country;
        this.TotalPages=TotalPages;
        this.sAccountNo=sAccountNo;
        this.sCurrentDate=sCurrentDate;
    }
    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer,Document document) {
        Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
        String img = System.getProperty("user.dir")  +"\\TemplateGeneration\\dhofar_logo.jpg";
         
        Console.log("Path IS :: " + img);
        Image image;
        try {
            image = Image.getInstance(img);
            image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getRight()-60,rect.getTop()-120);
            image.scalePercent(40f, 28f);
            writer.getDirectContent().addImage(image, true);
        
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.log("Some Error : "+e);
        }
        Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("Account Name \t:\t ",bfBold12);
        Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk(this.name,bfnormal12);
        Phrase p = new Phrase();
        p.add(chunk1); p.add(chunk2);
        
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT , p, rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getTop()-120,0);
        chunk1 = new Chunk("Account Number \t:\t ",bfBold12);
        chunk2 = new Chunk(this.sAccountNo, bfnormal12);
        p = new Phrase();
        p.add(chunk1); p.add(chunk2);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT , p, rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getTop()-140,0);
        chunk1 = new Chunk("PO BOX : ",bfBold12);
        chunk2 = new Chunk(this.POBOX, bfnormal12);
        p = new Phrase();
        p.add(chunk1); p.add(chunk2);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT , p, rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getTop()-155,0);
        chunk1 = new Chunk("Postal Code : ",bfBold12);
        chunk2 = new Chunk(this.PC, bfnormal12);
        p = new Phrase();
        p.add(chunk1); p.add(chunk2);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT , p, rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getTop()-165,0);
        chunk1 = new Chunk("City : ",bfBold12);
        chunk2 = new Chunk(this.City, bfnormal12);
        p = new Phrase();
        p.add(chunk1); p.add(chunk2);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT , p, rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getTop()-175,0);
        chunk2 = new Chunk(this.Country, bfnormal12);
        p = new Phrase();
        p.add(chunk2);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT , p, rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getTop()-185,0);
    }
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer,Document document) {
        Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(this.initiatedby+"-"+sCurrentDate,bfnormal12), rect.getLeft()+20, rect.getBottom()+20, 0);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("Page %s of "+this.TotalPages, writer.getPageNumber()),bf12),
                rect.getRight()/2, rect.getBottom()+20, 0);
        
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),Element.ALIGN_RIGHT , new Phrase(this.wi_name,bf12), rect.getRight()-20, rect.getBottom()+20,0);
    }
}
```

**

I looked for solutions online but could'nt find any. Neither I am getting any error during pdf generation. It is that only blank pages are getting created when data exceeds more than 1 page. Would love your feedback or any solution which can help.

Comment: If this works on your local machine and only fails on the server, you should compare your local computer and the server, e.g. in respect to versions of. Net runtimes, installed libraries, permissions on accessed resources,...